# Reactive web-crawler with limited concurrent request to the same domain

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm working on an open-source [web crawling project](https://github.com/bottomless-archive-project/library-of-alexandria). I noticed that the application occasionally flood the websites it's crawling with requests (I get back `429 Too Many Requests`). Because of this, I want to limit the concurrent request count to one with a one-second delay between requests for the same domain.

I figured out this code to do that:

```
Flux.generate(downloaderQueueConsumer)
    .doFirst(this::initializeProcessing)
    .flatMap(this::evaluateDocumentLocation)
    .groupBy(this::parseDocumentDomain, 100000)
    .flatMap(documentSourceItem1 -> documentSourceItem1
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .doOnNext(this::incrementProcessedCount)
            .flatMap(this::downloadDocument)
            .flatMap(this::archiveDocument)
            .doOnNext(this::incrementArchivedCount)
    )
    .doFinally(this::finishProcessing)
    .subscribe();
```

My problem with this code is that it doesn't limit parallel request count to a domain to one. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You'd probably need to maintain some sort of state external to the `Flux` if you wanted to do it this way. That being said, this isn't the approach I'd recommend for rate limiting - you may wish to map a 429 to a rate limit exception, then look at using `reactor-extra` and [`Retry`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/retry/Retry.html) to use exponential backoff with jitter.

Comment: Not sure for which part of your code you want to limit concurrency. You can switch to using `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` which ensures sequential execution. And `flatMap` also has an optional concurrency parameter which gives you some control.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I tried your suggestion because it sounds like a clever one! :) https://github.com/bottomless-archive-project/library-of-alexandria/blob/d96dc1ffa51ef6d38cde59486f7d46650c2521f3/loa-service/loa-io-service/src/main/java/com/github/loa/url/service/FileDownloader.java However, for some reason, when a sudden spike of the errors happens (like 30-100 under a few seconds), the processing of the application slows down. It feels like that retry is blocking some of the processing threads. Do you know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: @LakatOnosGyula Not sure. You could try using a `flatMap` instead of `doOnNext` (returning `Mono.error` in case of a 429) but I doubt that'd have much impact on performance. You could also try just having a single Exception created rather than creating a new one each time, as it could be the stack trace that's slow - but again, I doubt it if you're talking about just 30-100 in a seconds, I'd imagine you'd need many thousands before noticing the difference if that were the cause.

Comment: @MichaelBerry The problem is not because of the exception or raw performance loss. For some reason when a couple of hundred items are under retry, then the data flow stops for new items/signals. It feels like the flow could only handle ~150-250 concurrent/parallel items. After some time when the retries finished (everything is downloaded correctly) it's up to the initial speed. Sadly I yet to learn reactor enough to be able to figure out what's the problem. Maybe there is a limit on active subscriptions somewhere? It is being called by a flatMap on a Flux. There must be a limit on that.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I guess it could be reactor.util.concurrent.Queues#SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE. I will look into it tomorrow and come back here to document the results. :)

Comment: @MichaelBerry Now it's working fine even when many retries are going on. Sadly my test data is not uniform enough to figure out what caused the issue exactly. If you write your solution as an answer I'm more than happy to accept it! :)

Comment: @LakatosGyula I've done that - if you can form a reliable minimal reproducible example that shows the performance degradation, feel free to open another question and I'll take a look.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I start to feel that something is messed up in my data or tests. I'll look into that and will raise a new question if necessary. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably need to maintain some sort of state external to the Flux if you wanted to do it this way - there's no obvious way to store and alter this sort of mutable data within the Flux itself.

That being said, this isn't the approach I'd recommend for rate limiting - I've instead done something similar to the following which is a nicer and more robust solution:

- Map a 429 status code to a "rate limit" exception (you'll likely need to define this exception type yourself)
- Pull in reactor-extra, then use `Retry` to use exponential backoff with jitter (or whatever backoff strategy you prefer.)

This will give you more control over your specific retry strategy as well as likely making your code more readable.